# How to render Hair in Renderman

Tags: renderman-render-engine

I am new to Renderman and I can't figure out how to render hair. I tried finding info but I can only find how to do it in Maya which doesn't have the same workflow. I found this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bfbu6IH1XRQ&t=314s but it is in spanish. I tried following along and it seems like I did everything right, but still no luck.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I guess something was going on with "IT". After restarting it works the same as Cycles.

Just a glitch.